# Ошибка в коде OpenCV Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Есть код:

```py
import numpy as np 
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("example.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
cv2.imwrite("gray.jpg", gray)

edged = cv2.Canny(gray, 10, 250)
cv2.imwrite("edged.jpg", edged)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7, 7))
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(edged, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imwrite("closed.jpg", closed)

cnts = cv2.findContours(closed.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]
total = 0

for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)

    if len(approx) == 4:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [approx], -1, (0, 255, 0), 4)
        total += 1

print("Найдено: {0} книги".format(total))
cv2.imwrite("output.jpg", image)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\andre\Documents\Projects\2020\Python\Book Detection\find_books.py", line 20, in <module>
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.3.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\shapedescr.cpp:280: error: (-215:Assertion failed) count >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'cv::arcLength'
```

Что делать?

Comment: Посмотрите ответы здесь, может что-то подойдёт: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33067821/opencv-with-python-error-for-arclength

Comment: @CrazyElf Не подошло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот этот вариант строки дает полностью рабочий код.

```
cnts,_= cv2.findContours(closed.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

[image: До обработки]
[image: После обработки]

Comment: Добавлю только, что число выделенных полигонов на второй картинке 12, а программа выдает 13.

Comment: Но у автора ошибка в строке `peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)`

Comment: @gil9red Ну, может это наведённая ошибка, может `findContours` с параметром `RETR_EXTERNAL` даёт такие значения, которые потом не нравятся `arcLength`

Comment: @gil9red Я по статье код писал: https://tproger.ru/translations/finding-books-python-opencv/

Comment: Ошибался, сорян :)

Comment: 2  gil9red: Ошибка была потому, что там векторное значение требовалось для обработки.
Значение c берется из цикла: for c in cnts:
Поэтому по типу значения cnts в строке: peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)  и возникала ошибка.